# VBA to click Internet Explorer based on caption/text

Tags: vba

Good day to All!
This is my first time to post question here, please move this question to the right thread if necessary. I am new to IE manipulation using VBA and VBA is the only thing I know in programming. I am trying to click different buttons(or elements) in IE but I cant seem to find a way to do it. I've been searching for more than 3 days (8 hours a day) now but still no luck. Can anyone please forward me to the right track? The DOM explorer shows below line(or codes). Thank you so much in advance.

I only need to click "click b" (i added the spaces to avoid conversion)

< l i  c l a s s = " n a m e "  > c l i c k   a < / l i > 
 < l i   c l a s s = " n a m e "   > c l i c k   b < / l i >

working Codes ive used so far (but for other button-I cant seem to apply it for the above code)

```
For each element in ObjIE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    if instr(1,element.getattribute("src"), "xxx") > 0 then
      element.click
      exit for
    end if
Next element
```

Comment: For each element in ObjIE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    if instr(1,element.getattribute("src"), "xxx") > 0 then
      element.click
      exit for
    end if
Next element